# Employer asking us to provide SSN to a military customer

Tags: security, privacy

I work for a local trucking company.  We deliver to many job sites in all places for our customers who are running them.  Today two drivers went to military base.  Typically one provides their birth date, license number, and social security number to an armed service member at the front gate.  Once approved they can enter.

Upon arrival both drivers were stopped at the gate.  Both drivers received a phone call from someone who works a the company (our customer) who may or may not have actually been on site.  They were asked to provide their social security number to the unknown person at the company so that they could use that for the background check at the base.  Both drivers refused.  Management was furious, and called each of them and told them they should provide their SSN to the unknown person from the company who was asking for it.  They still did not provide their information and eventually turned back and left without making the delivery.

They believe that they should not because they do not know that the company might do with it.  They could lose it, they could use it for fraud, or one of their own employees who may have criminal record or no work authorization.

There is supposed to be a procedure in place for visitor authorization.  The company is supposed to provide us with a written request for the information to be used for the background check at the base.  This was brought up before they left and they were told not to worry about it.  Obviously this was not done prior to their arrival.

The company will likely ask someone else to try this again this week and I am concerned they will ask me.  My thoughts are that that company did not put in the required authorization request in the first place, or were scrambling to do it at the last minute.  I am also concerned about providing my SSN to anyone other than a uniformed service member.

Is it illegal for a company to ask for an employee to provide their SSN to a customer?  Even for the purposes of a background check?  If so, how can anyone be sure that it will be used properly and disposed of?  Like I said, the company could write it down and lose it, or someone else could find it, or it could be used for another purpose other than the one time background check.

Can the employees face disciplinary action for refusal?

I might make it clear up front that I am not comfortable providing this information myself to anyone other than a service member.  Could I face retaliation?  If so, should I file a complaint with HR or the EEOC?  Are there any legal protections to keeping ones personally identifiable information private in a situation like this?

Comment: Read the requirements of this marine base for vendors (as an example): https://www.lejeune.marines.mil/Base-Access/Contractors/ They seem to have secure ways of obtaining your documents. Also, they have a list of crimes that would get you a denial (maybe send that list to your colleague). And yes, you can probably get fired if you can't do your delivery. The EEOC won't help with that. And neither will HR.

Comment: "_This was brought up before they left and they were told not to worry about it._" You need to talk to the person who told them not to worry about it. Asking this question here won't help you much.

Comment: Also, "_Typically one provides their birth date, license number, and social security number to an armed service member at the front gate_". Why "_Both drivers refused_" ? You're contradicting yourself.

Comment: Who dispatched the drivers ? Your company ? Or the customer company ? Whoever dispatched the drivers is responsible for this incident. You don't send a truck loads of stuff to a military base without prior coordination.

Comment: Nobody, just to clarify.  The drivers refused to provide their SSN to someone from the customers company.  They were not asked by an official on that base.  I have provided my information to a guard at another place before, and went in without any trouble.  But if a customer was asking me for it, instead of filling out the correct authorization form beforehand, I would not and will not provide it.  There is a correct way to request a visitor and out customer was not doing it correctly.

Comment: Your customers company doesn't know who are going to be the drivers (it could be changed at the last minute). It is your company (trucking company)'s responsibility to notify the customer who the drivers are and provide the SSN. The drivers are supposed to ask your company to provide their SSN to the customer, not to give out the info to a stranger. At the end of the day, your company is responsible for all of these.

Comment: I think the big things that the answers so far have not addressed is: What is the proper procedure? Did they follow the proper procedure?
Answers keep saying you could be disciplined. But being disciplined for following company policy seems like something that could lead to a lawsuit. And similarly disregarding company policy and providing information when not authorised might also lead to problems for the employees

Comment: @TheEvilMetal From the [OP's comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/193767/employer-asking-us-to-provide-ssn-to-a-customer#comment638679_193767), they seem to know there is a procedure. The problem seems to be who should follow the procedure ? The OP's company or the customer company. I keep telling OP it's the OP's company because the delivery company makes the delivery, the OP seems to disagree.

Comment: @Nobody - I have some familiarity with the process the author describes.  The only individuals who can request access to the military base, is the individuals themself, it appears that the individual requesting the information was attempting to help the individuals onto the base but it was misguided at best and shows a lack of their understand of the process.  Now if the individuals requesting access to the base, are routinely going onto the base, there is a process to make it so that request process is valid for a longer period of time than a day.

Comment: Additionally, The company not the customer should be arranging long-term access to the base, part of that process will require the customer to provide the justification and essentially be the sponsor of the individual(s) coming on to the base.

Comment: @Donald Suppose the process at that base is the same as you described in your comment, why didn't the drivers  provide their SSN to the base ? If they did, this question would not be asked in the first place.

Comment: @Nobody - It sounds like the sponsor contacted the drivers.  The author indicates they have given it to the military policy at the gate in the past.

Comment: @Donald Then the author should have known that there is such policy (given out SSN), why did the author ask this question ? Why not let the drivers give their SSN to the guard ? This whole question is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @Nobody - The author indicated that the drivers did provided their own information to the base military police.

Comment: @Donald I don't see it. All I saw is this: "_They still did not provide their information and eventually turned back and left without making the delivery._" in the question.

Comment: It goes without saying that the real solution is to adjust our laws so that a stranger knowing your SSN isn't able to make any illicit gain from it. They are simply unique identifiers for every American tax payer, but many agencies have been treating them like passwords.

Answer (score 10):

Every military base has a procedure for getting onto that base. The trucking company needs to determine the exact procedure, and follow the procedure. In some cases it is easier to get a small number of drivers pre-approved instead of many drivers approved just in case they are needed, or do it on a ad-hoc basis which can take a ton of time for each delivery.

I would not provide my SSN over the phone to an unknown person. There should be no needed for this unsecure step.

I see construction vehicles, busses, food trucks, UPS, and FEDEX trucks drive onto bases every day. Sometimes they have to go in a specific gate, or report to a specific office. Sending drivers to the base and hope they can get through isn't a good plan.

> Is it illegal for a company to ask for an employee to provide their
> SSN to a customer? Even for the purposes of a background check? If so,
> how can anyone be sure that it will be used properly and disposed of?
> Like I said, the company could write it down and lose it, or someone
> else could find it, or it could be used for another purpose other than
> the one time background check.

They can ask. Any government facility has access procedures. Usually the SSN is needed before they will process a visit request.

Normally there are forms that are submitted. They usually explain the purpose of the information, and how it will be protected.

> Can the employees face disciplinary action for refusal?

Of course they could face disciplinary action. If this was a large part of the job, and you refused to make deliveries to military bases your refusal would limit the number of routes you can support, and your job would be at risk. But if they made a lot of deliveries to military bases, the company would follow the procedures to make those deliveries more efficient. It appears they haven't followed the procedures.

Comment: ^^^^^This is the correct answer. Especially this: "I would not provide my SSN over the phone to an unknown person. There should be no needed for this unsecure step." No ifs, ands, or buts ...

Answer (score 5):

If you live in a state with at-will employment, you won't have any recourse if you're fired over this unless you're in a union.

If you live in a right-to-work state or you're in a union, you may have some protections.

EEOC deals with *discrimination*, and for any kind of recourse you'd be dealing with your state's Department of Labor.

It does sound as if this process was bungled and done at the last minute, and both drivers were smart to refuse such information.  Maybe the customer is inexperienced, because access controls at military bases have always been around.

Comment: "Right-to-work" means that a worker is not forced to join a union or pay dues. It has nothing to do with employment protection.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked at or for many government sites. ALL of them require any and all visitors to provide photo ID with SSN to security before you're allowed to enter (usually at a front desk or guard office as soon as you arrive).

Usually visitors need to be pre-announced, complete with the numbers of their ID and SSN by the person who is arranging for their visit, usually hours if not days in advance. I'm highly surprised that this wasn't made clear to you before you took on the job, but it's standard practice. I'm also surprised you didn't have to supply that information before you even set out on the drive, rather than after arriving at the gate.

Comment: The company I work for is disorganized and dishonest.  The driver would have given their information to someone on the base who asked for it, but not some random person from the subcontractor company there were delivering to who called them on their personal phone and asked for it.  

I think we have all been to a secure facility at least one, and check in at the guard office and do the background check there.  This one should have been arranged beforehand by the customer.  Not while they were waiting outside for them to get their paperwork together.

Comment: @abettik "_This one should have been arranged beforehand by the customer._" **No**, This one should have been arranged beforehand by **your** company because the delivery is made by your company, not your customer.

Comment: @Nobody either, but usually the company doing the actual delivery does the paperwork after being instructed to do so by the company contracting them. It is ALWAYS the responsibility of the person executing the contract to have their paperwork in order.

Comment: Usually, the two companies should coordinate. The customer company has no way to know the SSN. The delivery company does. (How do they pay the drivers without SSN ?) The delivery company failed to provide the SSN. The responsibility is on them. The question is about whether the drivers should provide the SSN to a stranger. The answer is no. But, the delivery company does have that info. The OP asked the wrong question, wasted everybody's time. @abettik

Comment: Unfortunate that government sites do this, given that SSA themselves [deprecate the use of SSN as an identifier](https://www.ssa.gov/phila/ProtectingSSNs.htm): "We strongly urge all organizations that use SSNs as the identifier in their record keeping systems to use alternate identifiers... Organizations should avoid using Social Security numbers (SSNs) as identifiers for any type of transaction."

Comment: @GBsupportsthemodstrike they're using the SSN to verify the authenticity of the visitor's other identification, like passport and/or driver's license. It's not used as the sole identification and shouldn't be. Installations like this you don't get in using just a social security card, but the number is cross referenced with other things like passport numbers, finger prints, whatever depending on the security level required.

Comment: @jwenting I get that, but AFAICT the SSA discourages its use as *any* kind of identifier, outside those cases which are specifically legislated. It wasn't designed to be a universal national ID system.